# Redis - Python example of xadd and xread

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis

Could you give a very simple example of using Redis' `xread` and `xadd` in Python ( that displays the type and format of return values form xread and input of xadd)? I've already read many documentation but none of them are in Python.

The Redis [doc](https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro) gives an example:

```
> XADD mystream * sensor-id 1234 temperature 19.8
1518951480106-0
```

but If I try in python:

```py
sample = {b"hello":b"12"}
id = r.xadd("mystream", sample)
```

I get this error:

```py
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

make sure to flush before running just to make sure that there doesn't exist a list / stream with the same name. :

```
redis-cli flushall
```

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
    encoder = JSONEncoder()
    sample = {"hello": encoder.encode([1234,125, 1235, 1235])} # converts list to string
    stream_name = 'mystream'

    for i in range(10):
        r.xadd(stream_name, sample)

    # "$" doesn't seem to work in python
    read_samples = r.xread({stream_name:b"0-0"})
```

Comment: This is the same with all Redis data types though – if you have e.g. a list, you can't access it with set functions, etc.

Answer (score 10):

Based on redis-py [documentation](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/redis/client.html#Redis.xread):

Redis intitalization:

```
redis = redis.Redis(host='localhost')
```

To add a key-value pair (key-value should be a dictionary):

```
redis.xadd(stream_name, {key: value})
```

Block to read:

```
redis.xread({stream_name: '$'}, None, 0)
```

1. stream_name and ID should be a dictionary.
2. $ means the most new message.

> Moreover, instead of passing a normal ID for the stream mystream I
>   passed the special ID $. This special ID means that XREAD should use
>   as last ID the maximum ID already stored in the stream mystream, so
>   that we will receive only new messages, starting from the time we
>   started listening.[from here](https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro)

3. COUNT should be NONE if you want to receive the newest, not just any number of messages.
4. 0 for BLOCK option means Block with a timeout of 0 milliseconds (that means to never timeout)

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the help (or the docstrings [(1)](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/31519e4ccef49fb59254ee5524007c81faa7e850/redis/client.py#L2182-L2190), [(2)](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/31519e4ccef49fb59254ee5524007c81faa7e850/redis/client.py#L1965-L1974)) for the functions, they're quite straightforward:

```
>>> import redis
>>> r = redis.Redis()
>>> help(r.xadd)
    xadd(name, fields, id='*', maxlen=None, approximate=True)

    Add to a stream.
    name: name of the stream
    fields: dict of field/value pairs to insert into the stream
    id: Location to insert this record. By default it is appended.
    maxlen: truncate old stream members beyond this size
    approximate: actual stream length may be slightly more than maxlen

>>> help(r.xread)
    xread(streams, count=None, block=None)

    Block and monitor multiple streams for new data.
    streams: a dict of stream names to stream IDs, where
               IDs indicate the last ID already seen.
    count: if set, only return this many items, beginning with the
           earliest available.
    block: number of milliseconds to wait, if nothing already present.
```

Comment: I can't figure out with just the doc, as I've clearly said: " I've already read many documentation but none of them are in Python." So a working example would be appreiciated

Comment: That is literally the Python library's documentation, it's as Python as it can get. Have you just tried using those functions?

Comment: yes. First, I had to `redis-cli flushall`. Second, `"$"` doesn't seem to work in python, ( please correct me if I'm wrong ).

Comment: The OP is asking for an actual example, not a link to documentation.

Comment: The "$" works for blocking streams. like so, `>>> r.xread({'example': "$"}, count=None, block=0)` at this point the cursor waits till new messages arrive and prints that.